# Operations in JS not being accepted by angular2 with Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I got an example for a graph in d3 and I'm facing difficulty to implement this on my angular 2 typescript application. It's on the lines that's contains the "----> Error" comment.

No idea about how to solve this. Any help ?

```
d3.transition().duration(d3.event.altKey ? 7500 : 750).each(function () {
      path.exit().transition()
        .style("fill-opacity", function (d) {
          return d.depth === 1 + (root === p) ? 1 : 0; //----> Error: Operator '+' cannot be applied to types '1' and 'boolean'.
        })
        .attrTween("d", function (d) {
          return arcTween.call(this, exitArc(d));
        })
        .remove();

      path.enter().append("path")
        .style("fill-opacity", function (d) {
          return d.depth === 2 - (root === p) ? 1 : 0; //----> Error: The right-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number' or an enum type.
        })
        .style("fill", function (d) {
          return d.fill;
        })
        .on("click", zoomIn)
        .on("mouseover", mouseOverArc)
        .on("mousemove", mouseMoveArc)
        .on("mouseout", mouseOutArc)
        .each(function (d) {
          this._current = enterArc(d);
        });


      path.transition()
        .style("fill-opacity", 1)
        .attrTween("d", function (d) {
          return arcTween.call(this, updateArc(d));
        });


    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First error:

```
return d.depth === 1 + (root === p) ? 1 : 0; //----> Error: Operator '+' cannot be applied to types '1' and 'boolean'.
```

You cannot add `1 + (root === p)`. Most likely you need to shift the parentheses:

```
return d.depth === 1 + (root === p ? 1 : 0);
```

Second one:

```
return d.depth === 2 - (root === p) ? 1 : 0; //----> Error: The right-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number' or an enum type.
```

Same as the first. Here you are trying to subtract a boolean `(root === p)` from the number `2`. Again moving the parentheses will cure the error (if it gives you  what you intended).

```
return d.depth === 2 - (root === p ? 1 : 0);
```

Although in both cases it seems a bit convoluted. You could just remove the addition/subtraction entirely:

```
return d.depth === (root === p ? 2 : 1);
```

Comment: Awesome, Duncan ! tyvm !